# What is the song that plays when Lelouch sees the memories of C.C. in episode 11?

Tags: music, code-geass

In *Code Geass: Hangyaku no Lelouch* episode 11, around 16:00 mark, there is a song that starts to play when Lelouch sees the memories of C.C. Again, in the same episode at 19:50, the same song plays for the second time.

I didn't recall hearing this song before episode 11, and episode 13 at 7:35 as well.

I couldn't find the soundtrack from OSTs. What is it?

Comment: Additional Info;

Again in episode 11 at 19:50 same song plays for second time, For me I didnt hear this song before episode 11 and I am not sure if this song plays in future episodes as well.

PS. I Watched both episodes about 1 year ago and now I wanted to watch them one more time.

Comment: Additional Info: As I checked further episodes I learned that it plays in episode 13 at 7:35 as well still couldnt find the soundtrack, will look for it in further episodes

Answer (score 1):

It's an unreleased piece from the soundtrack called **Sins and Astonishment**. You can find it here:

[Code Geass: Unreleased Album - 07 Sins and Astonishment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGJCiW2HL74&list=PLb4mticUuCmQSnQpXJDttkzbhOxAdnGWf&index=7)

Answer (score 0):

idk what u talking about the song playing for the second time. but the song that played at the psychedelic trip scene was a song by hitomi kuroishi, titled: Strange Girl.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBo-YxCM1xU